# BASH: Evaluate $1 to a String to Call an Array Length

Tags: arrays, bash, function, variables, parameters

I have written this function here:  I want to run it like this,  `choose "title";`

```
function choose {
    echo $1;
    randNum=$RANDOM
    let "numChoices=${#$1[@]}";
    let "num=$randNum%$numChoices";
    i=0;

    while [ $i -lt $numChoices ]; do
        if [ $i -eq $num ]; then
            echo ${$1[$i]};
            break;
        fi
        ((i++));
    done
}
```

When it runs, I want the end product to be identical to this: (replace all $1's with title)

```
function choose {
    echo title;
    randNum=$RANDOM
    let "numChoices=${#title[@]}";
    let "num=$randNum%$numChoices";
    i=0;

    while [ $i -lt $numChoices ]; do
        if [ $i -eq $num ]; then
            echo ${title[$i]};
            break;
        fi
        ((i++));
    done
}
```

However, all I get is this error:

```
notify.sh: line 67: numChoices=${#$1[@]}: bad substitution
```

After quite a bit of documentation scouring, I haven't been able to understand the substitutions and pointers and references well enough.  Could someone help out with some insight, and maybe correct my syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were using bash 4.3, you could use nameref variables, like this: (I also updated various parts of your script.)

```
choose() {
    echo $1
    # This makes theVar an alias ("nameref") to the variable whose name is in $1
    # Like any declare inside a function, it is implicitly local.
    declare -n theVar=$1
    local randNum=$RANDOM
    local numChoices=${#theVar[@]}
    local num=$(( randNum % numChoices ))
    local i

    for (( i=0; i < numChoices; ++i )); do
        if (( i == num )); then
            echo "${theVar[i]}"
            break;
        fi
    done
}
```

But you probably don't have bash 4.3, since it's less than a year old and most distros are very conservative about bash updates. So you'll need to use old-style indirection syntax `${!name}`. Unfortunately, that is awkward for array references because you need to make `name` include the entire subscript expression. And, worse, as far as I know it doesn't handle array length at all (or, for that matter, scalar length). You could get the array length using `eval`, but my general bias against eval leads to the alternative implementation below:

```
choose() {
    echo $1
    local randNum=$RANDOM
    # For the indirection, we need to construct the indexed name.
    local name=$1[@]
    # This hack makes varSize a row of dots with one dot per element.
    local varSize=$(printf ".%.0s" "${!name}")
    local numChoices=${#varSize}
    local num=$(( randNum % numChoices ))
    local i

    for (( i=0; i < numChoices; ++i )); do
        if (( i == num )); then
            # Again, we need to construct the complete indexed name.
            name=$1[$i]
            echo "${!name}";
            break;
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: your alternative seemed to have worked for me, thanks!  that's what I needed to happen.

Comment: @DrewDiezel: Cool. But keep the 4.3 version around for when you upgrade.